# Grouping a List and selecting the required item after ordering

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of type Course with around 100 rows. Course has 3 columns: Code, Description and Year. So the list currently looks like:

```
Code    Description   Year
A200    DataB         2018
A200    DataB         2019
A300    DataC         2018
A400    DataD         2019
A500    DataA         2018
A500    DataA         2019
```

I want to be able to return the latest row for each year, and then order the results by the description alphabetically. So the final results should be

```
A500    DataA    2019 (Latest A500 row and ordered by Description)
A200    DataB    2019 (Latest A200 row)
A300    DataC    2018
A400    DataD    2019
```

I have tried a variation of:

```
List<Course> NewAllCourses = AllCourses
    .GroupBy(x => x.CourseCode)
    .Select(g => g.Last().CourseYear)
    .OrderBy(y => y.CourseDescription)
    .ToList();
```

but I cant seem to get the syntax correct and getting different errors for each version I try. Any help would be appreciated as I have been trying this for hours now as I don't fully understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there with your code, the only thing wrong with it is that your Select() call is only selecting the CourseYear value, where you want to select the whole object so you can keep working on it.

Something a bit like this should work:

```
List<Course> NewAllCourses = AllCourses
    .GroupBy(x => x.CourseCode)
//Select the last item from the group, ordered by year. 
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.CourseYear).Last())
    .OrderBy(y => y.CourseDescription)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
List<Course> NewAllCourses = AllCourses
    .OrderByDescending(y => y.CourseYear)
    .ThenOrderBy(y => y.CourseDescription)
    .GroupBy(x => x.CourseCode)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ThenOrderBy` be `ThenBy`?

Comment: I think you need to order by `Description` *after* you do the `Select`